# Bootstrap - carousel same height than others div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem for adjust the height of my carousel.

I have a row like this :

row [ col-md-9 [ my caroussel ] , col-md-3[..] ]

The height of col-md-3 is higher than that of col-md-9.

The `Fiddle` of my problem :

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16241/)

The red box is my col-md-9 and I want the caroussel takes all height of this col.

Thank you

Comment: So, nobody for help me ?

Comment: So my caroussel can't takes all height of red box ?